# How to use jQuery UI Calendar/Date PIcker for week rather than day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I've been using the jQuery UI Calendar / Date Picker with great success over the last couple months.  I've been given a new requirement to allow for a week to be selected (Sun - Sat) rather than a single day.

Has anyone accomplished this before?

- highlighting by week rather than day
- show beginning date and ending date rather than single date in textbox / labels

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Inline week picker using jQuery UI DataPicker (requires jQuery UI 1.8+):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }

    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));
            $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));

            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });

    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="week-picker"></div>
    <br /><br />
    <label>Week :</label> <span id="startDate"></span> - <span id="endDate"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

run it on JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/manishma/AVZJh/light/

Comment: This is great but only works for inline display of datepicker (attached to div or span). Any suggestions how to modify this whena ttached to regular text field?

Comment: Quick question...what's the proper startDate and endDate if I set 'firstDay: 3'

Comment: `var $calendarTR = $('.ui-weekpicker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr');
            $calendarTR.live('mousemove', function() {
                $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover');
            });` its not working `jquery-1.9.0b1.min.js` above versions.

Comment: Replace .live() with .on()

$calendarTR.on('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });

Comment: NOTE - because live() binded the event to *future* DOM Nodes and on() doesnt. There are some changes required. Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/TZtes/1/   for some reason it doesnt work in the fiddle, probably because of the way the inner html child is handled, however it does work in any external setup (I copied and pasted my code). So yeah just wanted to share a version that works for jQuery 1.9+

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. But I also need to select a date some times. User will select either a date range or a specific date. How can I make it work in this?

Comment: the replacement code for jQuery 1.7+ :
replace 
$('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
$('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });

with :
$(document).on( 'mousemove','.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr',function() {$(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
$(document).on('mouseleave','.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr',function() {$(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });

Comment: Wow, is the only thing that I can say to this answer. This is what Im looking for. Thanks men, great help

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way at going at it. 
 -Display the week with showWeek. 
- Define a beforeShow to attach an event handler using live() so the week row is highlighted (including the week number).
- Detach the event handler with die() onclose. This is particularly handy when you are using normal datepickers elsewhere in your code.

```
$( ".week-picker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showWeek: true,
    beforeShow: function(dateText, inst) { 

        // for week highighting
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar tr").live("mousemove", function() { 
            $(this).find("td a").addClass("ui-state-hover"); 
            $(this).find(".ui-datepicker-week-col").addClass("ui-state-hover");
        });
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar tr").live("mouseleave", function() { 
            $(this).find("td a").removeClass("ui-state-hover");
            $(this).find(".ui-datepicker-week-col").removeClass("ui-state-hover");      
        });
    },
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var wk = $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText));
        if (parseInt(wk) < 10) {
            wk = "0" + wk;
        }           
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();

        if (isNaN(wk)) {
            $(this).val("");
        } else {
            $(this).val(year + ";" + wk);
        }

        // disable live listeners so they dont impact other instances
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar tr").die("mousemove");
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar tr").die("mouseleave");

    }
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution, and works inline as well. Only, I would add one small modification; change `$(".ui-datepicker-calendar tr")` to `$(".ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr")` (adding `tbody` in two places).  This way, the 'Wk' in the header of the table won't jump when highlighting.  @Stijn Van Loo may be interested too.

Answer (score 6):

I have created a jQuery plugin based on the accepted answer. Get it at https://github.com/Prezent/jquery-weekpicker or through Bower. Example usage:

```
$('#selector').weekpicker({
    startField: '#date-start',
    endField: '#date-end'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need the following dependencies:

1. jquery.js
2. jquery-ui.min.js
3. jquery-ui.css

```js
  var startDate;
  var endDate;
  $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
    endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
    var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
    $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));
    $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));
    $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ) + " - " + $.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));
    }
  });
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar tr:hover { 
    background-color:#808080;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <label for="startDate">Date :</label>
    <input name="startDate" class="date-picker" />
    <label>Week :</label> <span id="startDate"></span> - <span id="endDate"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the jqueryui-1.10.2.js at line 8123 :

(I don't remember where I have seen this)

```
case 'W':  
output += this.iso8601Week(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()));
break;
```

Then you could select week with W in date format ==> dateFormat: 'yy-W'

```
$("#your_datepicker").datepicker ({ firstDay: 1, showWeek: true, showOtherMonths: true, dateFormat: 'yy-W'});
```

If you have a previous version of jqueryui, search for "@" (search the quotes also) in the file and add these 3 lines.

Comment: While this solution may work, ad-hoc patching of third-party libraries isn't a good idea since it guarantees your consumer code will break if/when the library is upgraded.

Comment: You're absolutely right. ;) But you know, sometimes, you want to break the rules ! ANARCHY !!!

Answer (score 0):

I used some of the above examples but took a different approach because I need to support selecting a week but the week could start on any day of the week and needs to change based on a variable.  I set up classes to group each td with a week class so I can easily highlight a week that overlaps a tr.  In this example, datepickerStartWeekDay can be 0 to 6 representing a week starting on Sunday to Saturday.

Here is my code:

```
var $elem = $("input.my-date-picker");
var weekCounter = 1;
var datepickerStartWeekDay = 1;

options = {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        weekCounter = 1;
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        if (datepickerStartWeekDay != null) {
            var elem = $(this);
            var date = elem.datepicker('getDate');
            var curDayNum = date.getDay();
            var offset;

            if (curDayNum > datepickerStartWeekDay) {
                offset = -(curDayNum - datepickerStartWeekDay);
            }
            else {
                offset = -(7 - (datepickerStartWeekDay - curDayNum));
            }
            var wkStartDate = new Date(date.addDays(offset));
            elem.val(wkStartDate);
        }
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var retClass;

        // datepickerStartWeekDay:  0 = Sunday.. 6 = Saturday
        // Set up weeks based on the start day with classes.
        // week1, week2, week3, etc based on the start day of the week
        if (datepickerStartWeekDay != null) {
            if (date.getDay() == datepickerStartWeekDay) {
                weekCounter += 1;
            }
            retClass = [true, 'week' + weekCounter];
        }
        else {
            retClass = [true, ''];
        }
        return retClass;
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        weekCounter = 1;
    }
};
$elem.datepicker(options);

// Event to list for mouseover for week selection
$(".ui-datepicker-calendar td").live('mouseover', function (ev) {
    var targetElem = $(ev.currentTarget);
    targetElem.closest("tbody").find(".ui-week-hover").removeClass("ui-week-hover");
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (targetElem.hasClass("week" + i)) {
            targetElem.closest("tbody").find(".week" + i).addClass("ui-week-hover");
            continue;
        }
    }
});`
```

// CSS

```
.ui-week-hover a {
    background-color: #eef6f9 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this if anyone is still interested: [Week Picker Converter](https://github.com/dnviti/jQueryWeekPicker).

Is a small field converter that converts text or hidden into the week picker.
If anyone is using it to print a table (from database) this is usable as well with the following pattern on an SQL Query select:

```
select
'<span class="displayWeek">'
|| week_field
|| '</span><input type="hidden" value="week_field" id="id_field" />'
|| '<i class="fa fa-calendar showCalendar" aria-hidden="true"
    style="cursor:pointer;margin-left: 10px;"
    onclick="javascript:showWeekCalendar(this, additionalFunction);"></i>'
as "WeekPicker"
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  var date = $('#FromDate').datepicker('getDate');
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  var year = date.getFullYear(); //get year
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var date1 = date.getDate();
  $("#ToDate").datepicker("setDate", date);

  $("#ToDate").datepicker({
    //In Datepicker set the Calendar display start with Monday

    firstDay: $('#FromDate').datepicker('getDate'),
    //stepMonths: 0 ,
    //month: date.getMonth(), 
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    startDate: new Date(month, date1, year), //set it here
    endDate: new Date(month, '31', year + 1),
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
      //var monday = new Date("June 1, 2013 00:00:00"); Used it for testing

      //Get today's date
      var monday = $('#FromDate').datepicker('getDate');

      //Set the time of today's date to 00:00:00
      monday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

      //alert(monday.getDay() + ' : ' + monday.getDate() + ' : ' + (monday.getDay() || 7) + ' : ' + monday); Used it for testing

      /*
      Below Line sets the Date to Monday (Start of that Week)
      (monday.getDay() || 7) returns the value of getDay()
      ie., [ 1 - Mon, 2 - Tue, 3 - Wed, 4 - Thu, 5 - Fri, 6 - Sat ]
      except for Sunday where it returns 7.
      The return value is used to calculate the Date of that Week's Monday
      */

      monday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 1 - (monday.getDay() || 7));

      //Set the Date to Monday
      var sunday = new Date(monday);

      //Now add 6 to Monday to get the Date of Sunday (End of that Week)
      sunday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 6);
      //Now return the enabled and disabled dates to datepicker
      return [(date >= monday && date <= sunday), ''];
    },

  });

  //Set the date format to dd/mm/yy ie., 30/10/1989
  $("#ToDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "mm/dd/yy");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
        $('#week-button').click(function() {
            var value = $("#weeklyDatePicker").val();
            const search = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
            search.set('week_start', value.split(" ")[0]);
            search.set('week_end', value.split(" ")[2]);
            location.search = search.toString();
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        moment.updateLocale('en', {
        week: { dow: 1 } // Monday is the first day of the week
        });

        //Initialize the datePicker(format mm-dd-yyyy)
        $("#weeklyDatePicker").datepicker({
            format: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
            firstDay: 1
        });

        //Get the value of Start and End of Week
        $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('change', function (e) {
            var value = $("#weeklyDatePicker").val();
            var firstDate = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(1).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            var lastDate =  moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(7).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(firstDate + " - " + lastDate);
        });
    });
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr:hover {
        background-color: #a768f3;
        color: #444444;
}
.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr:hover td , .ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr:hover a {
        background: transparent !important;
        color:#fff !important;
        font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input  autocomplete="off" class="week-picker form-control" type='text' name="week" id="weeklyDatePicker" placeholder="Select Week" />
```