# Combining jQuery ui datepicker and isotope data-filters

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I'm currently working with a jQuery ui datepicker and I'm trying to figure out if it is at all possible to combine the calendar with the isotope plugin, more specifically the data-filter, i.e. selecting a date from the datepicker and filtering out the relevant events (on that date).
Here's some of my html:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>

<div id="block-wrap">
    <div class="blocks">1</div>
    <div class="blocks">3</div>
    <div class="blocks">2</div>
    <div class="blocks">2</div>
    <div class="blocks">3</div>
    <div class="blocks">1</div>
    <div class="blocks">3</div>
    <div class="blocks">2</div>
    <div class="blocks">1</div>    
</div>
```

[Also a working demo on jsfiddle here too](http://jsfiddle.net/Deqvz/3/)
So is it at all possible to filter out the numbered blocks using the datepicker?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After a lot of to and fro I think [**onSelect**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) is your best choice. You can use the method's, string date representation or datepicker instance object to match any of your blocks and hide/show them as needed that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did look at this again.

You can use the datepicker's [**onSelect()**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) method and attach this:

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  //var dayValue = date.getDate(); // or
   var dayValue = inst.selectedDay;


  $blocks.show();

  $blocks.filter(function () {
    if (this.innerHTML != dayValue) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

You can use the first function parameter which holds a string version of the date you clicked or you can use the second parameter which is an instance of the datepicker object with useful properties values for the date elements.

---

[**DEMO 01**](http://jsfiddle.net/gEzNE/) - Only show boxes matching the number clicked in calendar

---

I had a play around and the `filter` option of the isotop must be a selector. As far as I know you cannot generate a jQuery selector interrogation the value or innerHTML.

However, you can add a custom attribute to each block containing the same value, similar to this:

```
<div class="blocks" data-value="1">1</div>
<div class="blocks" data-value="3">3</div>
<div class="blocks" data-value="2">2</div>
```

Now, you can generate a valid selector for the `filter` in the `OnSelect` method of the datepicker, like this:

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  var dayValue = inst.selectedDay;

  $container.isotope({
    filter: '[data-value="' + dayValue + '"]'
  });
}
```

---

[**DEMO 02**](http://jsfiddle.net/YcnEB/) - Using data attributes to connect datepicker to isotope filter

---

Code from the DEMOs in case of link-rot:

---

**DEMO-01: HTML**

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<div id="block-wrap">
  <div class="blocks">1</div>
  <div class="blocks">3</div>
  <div class="blocks">2</div>
  <div class="blocks">2</div>
</div>
```

**DEMO-01: Script**

```
var $blocks = $("div.blocks", "#block-wrap");

$(function () {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    //nextText: '&rarr;',
    //prevText: '&larr;',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    //dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    //showOn: "button",
    //buttonImage: "img/calendar-blue.png",
    //buttonImageOnly: true,
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      var dayValue = date.getDate();

      $blocks.show();

      $blocks.filter(function () {
        if (this.innerHTML != dayValue) {
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});


var $container = $('#block-wrap');

$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.blocks',
    animationEngine: 'css',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: 5
    }


  });
});
```

**DEMO-02: HTML**

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<div id="block-wrap">
  <div class="blocks" data-value="1">1</div>
  <div class="blocks" data-value="3">3</div>
  <div class="blocks" data-value="2">2</div>
  <div class="blocks" data-value="2">2</div>
  <div class="blocks" data-value="1">1</div>
</div>
```

**DEMO 02 - Script (only onSelect changed when compared to DEMO 01 script)**

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  var dayValue = inst.selectedDay;
  $container.isotope({
    filter: '[data-value="' + dayValue + '"]'
  });
}
```

**CSS same for both DEMOs**

```
#datepicker {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
#block-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 230px;
  top: 10px;
  width: auto;
}
.blocks {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: silver;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;
}
.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
  z-index: 1;
}
.isotope, .isotope .isotope-item {
  /* change duration value to whatever you like */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.isotope {
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
  -moz-transition-property: height, width;
  -ms-transition-property: height, width;
  -o-transition-property: height, width;
  transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
  -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform, opacity;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
/**** disabling Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
 .isotope.no-transition, .isotope.no-transition .isotope-item, .isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

Comment: amazing solution, thank you! I was wondering though whether the datepicker could be combined with the data-filters in the isotopes plugin (loaded into the fiddle). I've used the data-filters many times before, but I've not a clue how it could be combined with the ui datepicker

Comment: @user1374796: As far as I was able to tell you cannot combine the datepicker with the isotope filter without a change to your HTML for the blocks. The `filter` option must be a selector but as far as I know a jQuery selector cannot use the innerHTML within it, i.e: `'[val="days"]'`, that doesn't work. However, using custom data attributes, containing the same value as your innerHTML you can use those as a valid selector. I updated my answer, adding that alternative, including a DEMO. I hope this is something you can work with.

Comment: @user1374796: Oh, I forgot to add, if you want the initial filter to be set to the blocks from today in the alternative `DEMO -02` you can set it like this `filter: '[data-value="' + $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate').getDate() + '"]',` - [**DEMO - 2.5**](http://jsfiddle.net/RVssZ/)

Comment: wow that's perfect, thank you so much for your help!! There might be one more thing you may know, is it possible for the data-values to be month specific? currently selecting a '1' from any months filters the '1's in the field. But as it will be acting as a calendar for events spanning a few months it might be helpful for the filters to be date specific, not just number specific, if that makes sense.

Comment: @user1374796: If not in `onSelect` you get the date object from `$('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate')` call. Then you can use JavaScript methods like `.getDate()` to get the desired values [**(relevant documentation)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) If you are in `onSelect` you have the paramters available to you, the first one being the text version and the second one `inst` being the datepicker instance. You can use it the same way. All you nee to do then is add the full date values to your data attribute and match the complete values.

Comment: @user1374796: For example in `onSelect` for a full date: `var date = new Date(dateText);` and `var dateValue = date.getDate().toString() + (date.getMonth()+1).toString() + date.getFullYear().toString();` The `dateValue` is then something like 112012 for 1st of January 2013 ( note that `getMonth()` returns 0-11 where 0 is January). Updated your data attribute similar to : `<div class="blocks" data-value="112013">1</div>` and off you go. [**DEMO 03 - Full dates**](http://jsfiddle.net/7RRUT/) The DEMOs are just examples. You need to work out yourself how you need it to fit in the end.

Comment: Just another question on this function, I'm trying to figure out how to utilise some more filters, a filter for today, this week and this month. i.e. pulling in the relevant data for each of those categories. Here's an updated fiddle with buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/7RRUT/2/ I did figure out how to get a 'today' filter working, but it wasn't quite right and only seemed to work the once. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @user1374796: I only seen your comment now, I will have a look but I can't realy until late tonight. I will send you an update unless you have it figured out by then.

Comment: cheers, any help would be great. I managed to get a click function to work for 'today' but it only filtered the 'day' value and not the full string date. Any suggestions via the fiddle are more than welcome!

Comment: @user1374796: selecting today is straight forward. But selecting current week/month is a little more code. I added the initial code for selecting today to [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7RRUT/3/) along with the link to the SO issue explaining how to select the current week, which you can easily adapt for month. For the isotop selection it's as simple as showing all divs which have a attribute value within a range, etc. The SO for current week is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224135/can-i-highlight-an-entire-week-in-the-standard-jquery-ui-date-picker

Comment: yes, I'd tried that for the 'today' function before, when I've changed the 'data-values' to '1422013' though it still doesn't seem to filter them out which is odd because it seems to be selecting it on the date pocket but not filter out the relevant content?

Comment: @user1374796: Yes, slight oversight on my part regarding the today click. the format you pass to the datepicker for selecting today has to be the date object, while the format you pass to the isotop filter has to be the concatonated string-parts. I have this working here now: http://jsfiddle.net/7RRUT/4/

Comment: I think I'm getting close, still not quite working though - http://jsfiddle.net/7RRUT/6/

Comment: apologies for this (again), this is the very last thing I need to do to finish my site and it's proving to be an absolute pain, I'm having no luck at all, any help would be massively appreciated because I can't figure it out at all: http://jsfiddle.net/7RRUT/7/

Comment: @user1374796: hi. Aside from the link I posted before which is doing the week/month selection I'm not sure either. It might help if you ask what you have left to do in a new question. List what you have and what you need exactly . That way more people can look at it, increasing the chance of someone hopefully knowing how to hook it up.