# How to select the week of a given date in jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to select or highlight the week of a given date '2015-03-03' in the jquery calendar.
Thank you.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224135/can-i-highlight-an-entire-week-in-the-standard-jquery-ui-date-picker

Comment: This is for selecting the week when you click on a day, but i want to select a week of an input date.