# javascript week picker

Tags: javascript, datetime

Can someone recommend a week picker which can be edited for example I need to change the names of the months to another language.

I saw this jQuery week picker, is it possible to change it a bit? as I said, I need to change month names to another language.

[Week Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289633/how-to-use-jquery-ui-calendar-date-picker-for-week-rather-than-day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert `monthNames: ["J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D"]`, where the array has 12 Strings that will be used as months' names, as a option when initializing your datepicker. 
I edited the jsfiddle from your linked post to show a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AVZJh/825/).

Comment: great example, I have one more thing to ask you. Do you know how can I get value of the week number after I add these lines in the code: `showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1` I just need to get that value as well

Comment: @denonth You get the week with the line `var week = $.datepicker.iso8601Week( $('.week-picker').datepicker("getDate"))`. For a test that alerts the week of the currently marked date if you click on the datepicker see http://jsfiddle.net/AVZJh/826/

Comment: hi can I ask you 2 more questions if it is possible as I see you know how does this date picker works. So if I want to change day names you know (monday, tuesday..) to something else. Second question will be: Is it possible to combine those 2 datepickers together? This one looks better for what I need and I think that it should be the same thing? LINK: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

Comment: @denonth To your first question: if you want to change the displayed daynames for the columns you can achieve it with adding `dayNamesMin: ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"]` like you did with `monthNames` before.

Comment: thank you do you know maybe how to make the second question to work?

Comment: do you think that this is possible to combine those two?

Comment: @denonth I'm not sure and tried to find some examples but was not succesful :( Do you want the mobile one because you like its design more?

Comment: yes that mobile one looks really nice and I am making a mobile optimized page and that should work for me... but in this example I have everything that I need for selecting weeks, getting week number and so on...and I need to combine those two..I don't know how to approach to that problem..I would appreciate if you could help me

Comment: @denonth I would look in the css that is used for styling the datepicker in http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

Comment: Hey I have one question :) how can I retrieve a start and end date in javascript and not in the html? If you know maybe?

Answer (score 2):

What you posted is based on jQuery UI Datepicker which **does support** localization, see [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization).

```
$("#datepicker" ).datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional["en"]);
```

Comment: so where can I put your code in the example that I have linked as this has working solution to select a week I just need to make it localized