# Getting jQuery var from input text

Tags: jquery, html

I found this datepicker [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289633/how-to-use-jquery-ui-calendar-date-picker-for-week-rather-than-day).

```
$(function () {
    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    var selectCurrentWeek = function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }

    $('.week-picker').datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings));
            $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings));

            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });

    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function () {
        $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover');
    });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover');
    });
});
```

How can I set `startDate` and `endDate` in my input text? I have tried with `id="startDate"` and `id="endDate"`. It works for a span tag, but not for an input.

```
<input name="startDate" type="text" id="startDate" required>
<input name="endDate" type="text" id="endDate" required>
```

Comment: If my answer didn't help, let me know. If it helped, then please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.val()` http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
$('#startDate').val('something');
```

Comment: Forgive my delay. As I have seen, val () works for get values, not for set them. Am i right?

Comment: I give you an example and a link that explain what it does: *Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements **or set the value of every matched element**.*

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation, I can't vote the answers.

Comment: I didn't say it was you! People rarely accept an answer and downvote it at the same time ;-)

Comment: Actully you get the value with `.val();` and you set the value with `.val('NewValue');` .. I'd recommend you read the jQuery basics before indulging into heavy jQuery coding. Make sure to check jsPref.com also on a later point to learn how different ways of writing jQuery can speedup/slowdown your very same code.