# Weekpicker using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datepicker

I’m having a hard time creating a “week picker” using [react-datepicker](http://hacker0x01.github.io/react-datepicker/).

I was searching up online and came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289633/how-to-use-jquery-ui-calendar-date-picker-for-week-rather-than-day) on stack overflow. The following is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishma/AVZJh/light/) from the answer

```
var startDate;
var endDate;

var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
    }, 1);
}

$('.week-picker').datepicker( {
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
        endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
        var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
        $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));
        $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));

        selectCurrentWeek();
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var cssClass = '';
        if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
            cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
        return [true, cssClass];
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        selectCurrentWeek();
    }
});

$('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
$('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
```

the answer uses jQuery and the jQuery Datepicker to create a week picker.

I want to implement this using React and the react-datepicker, but I’m not sure where to start.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I mean they seem to have some pretty good documentation about how to use it. what are you not understanding? what have you tried?