# The selected month doesn't display in the jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

Goal:
When I change the date from May to January 21 2016 and the page will be refresh and the then I click on the textbox you are enable to see the selected week and its dates in the datepicker. In other words, it display January in the datepicker.

Problem:
When you have selected for instance january 21 2016 and the current date is may 2016 the webpage will be updated and then 
I click on the text you see May 2016 instead of January 21. It is supposed to display January, not May.

I don't know what part is missing in order to achieve the goal.

Source code:

> jsfiddle.net/AVZJh/3058/

Info:
*I'm using asp.net mvc
*The reason the the page to be refresh is because I need to retrieve data from the database.
*The foundation of the customized code of datepicker is from these pages.

```
jsfiddle.net/manishma/AVZJh/light/
```

> [How to use jQuery UI Calendar/Date PIcker for week rather than day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289633/how-to-use-jquery-ui-calendar-date-picker-for-week-rather-than-day)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you set the date after the refresh. But when I add a value to the input it works for me. Here is an example:

```
<input class="week-picker" class="span10" type="text" value="03/27/2016" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AVZJh/3059/

Comment: I forgot to add the value in the jsfiddle. However if you refresh the webpage based on selectoin that is january then the result would be different.

Comment: But what do you mean with refresh the page? How do you refresh the page?. How do you pass your variables to the refreshed page? You might need to give us some of your ASP.NET code.

Comment: is there a jsfiddle for asp.net mvc?

Comment: No, just add it in the information about your question.

Comment: In the end, I solve it but I dont know how I did it. Thank you for your help!