# datepicker selection from saturday to saturday

Tags: jquery

I am looking to make a selection of a week or several weeks from Saturday to Saturday. But I do not find the solution at all. Here is what I already did:

```
    $(function () {
    // Si minimum_retail (minimum à prendre en jour) est supp à 1
    if (minimum_retail > 1) {
        weekpicker = 'week'
    } else {
        weekpicker = false;
    }

    $('#datepicker').dateRangePicker({
        firstDay: 2,
        alwaysOpen: true,
        format: 'DD/MM/Y',
        separator: ' au ',
        minDays: minimum_retail,
        startOfWeek: 'monday',
        batchMode: weekpicker,
        maxDate: "+1y",
        language: 'fr',
        inline: true,
        container: '#datePicker',
        showTopbar: false,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);

            var y = date.getFullYear().toString();
            var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
            var d = date.getDate().toString();
            if(m.length == 1){ m = '0' + m; }
            if(d.length == 1){ d = '0' + d; }
            var currDate = y+'-'+m+'-'+d;

            if (greetings.indexOf(currDate) >= 0){
                return [true, "ui-highlight"];
            }
            if (unavailableDates) {
                return [unavailableDates.indexOf(string) == -1]
            }


        }
    });
});
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery UI Calendar/Date PIcker for week rather than day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289633/how-to-use-jquery-ui-calendar-date-picker-for-week-rather-than-day)

Comment: Yes and no I try to make a selection from Saturday to Saturday and that I can accumulate the weeks