# How to display all weeks from two dates (not the number)

Tags: javascript

I want to show in a  all weeks between two dates and with  removing Saturday and Sunday from weeks.
so is there a function to get a list of days or weeks between two dates? 
i want to show some thing like That : 
when the user click the  there is as option:

Week 1 : From 15 to 19 October

Week 2 : From 22 to 26 October

Comment: why not use a calender?

Comment: `is there a function to get a list of days or weeks between two dates?` Certainly not, Probably in some library, Why not implement it yourself ? then when you get stuck, come here and ask for help.

Comment: @AyushGupta there is a calendar that force the user to choice just week? not only a date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery UI Calendar/Date PIcker for week rather than day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289633/how-to-use-jquery-ui-calendar-date-picker-for-week-rather-than-day)