# How can I implement a datepicker that selects a week of the year based on a rule?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, datepicker

I've been trying to find a solution to this, but I can't. I also can't believe it's this difficult to find.

Okay, how can I create or implement a datepicker that allows a user to pick just the week of the year? Also, how can I create or implement that datepicker so that it follows a rule that the first week of the year is based on?

For example, if the rule says that the first week of the year must be 4 calendar days, and Jan 1st falls on a Thursday. If the user picks the following week, they would get week 01. If the rule says that the first week of the year only needs to be 1 day, then the same selection by the user would return week 02.

I've found a number of javascript solutions that allow the week selection, but they don't allow a rule to be followed. Same with bootstrap, at least as far as I can tell.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Look for something close and get ideas - post that code that you wrote and why it has challenges and we might be able to fix it.  https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+week+picker&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS784US784&ei=QEkxYf3JG6Od_QaWr4GwAw&oq=javascript+week+picker&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoHCAAQRxCwAzoHCAAQsAMQQzoICAAQgAQQsQM6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOggIABAWEAoQHkoECEEYAFDHWliHcWCXiAFoAnACeACAAVuIAbUFkgECMTGYAQCgAQHIAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj96e7fpOHyAhWjTt8KHZZXADYQ4dUDCA8&uact=5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1289633/125981

Comment: Can the high voted answer shared above do some help in your case sir? In my position, your rule about select week may confuse users like : why I choose this week but the date picker showed the next week is active. So what about add code like `alert("pls select the next week")` in the `onChange` callback method?